# Would I qualify for the 2/5 year exclusion if I've only owned the property for 2 years?

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, capital-gains-tax

I’ve owned a property for 2 years exactly. I’ve lived in it for just over 12 months and have rented it out for 12 months so far.

I want to understand if I would pay taxes if my gain was under $250,000. If so, how much? Is it 30% of the gain? I’m confused because everything I’ve been reading talks about 2/5 years rule but what I’ve only had the property for 2 years total. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The 2/5 means you had to live in it for [2 of prior 5 years](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc701.html).

You did not do that, you turned it into a rental after 1 year. The gain exclusion does not apply to you.

Comment: I thought the 2/5 year "loophole" was closed in 2009.

Comment: I added an IRS link to my answer. No, the rules weren't changed in 2009.